# How to change date format in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

There are two date format used in shell script:

```
Format 1. 01-01-2014
Format 2. 2014-01-01
```

**Scenario:**
format 1 is a directory, while format 2 is file name.
I am trying to parse format 2 file using shell script, but stuck at one point.
I am managing call to directory having format 1 by defining all values in array, now for each array value I am parsing required file in format 2.
Now to manage array of format 2.
Problem can be solved if , I can do date conversion like in PHP.

```
$date='01-01-2014'
$filetosearch=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))
```

by doing above two steps I can get two different date format from one I define in array.
so such thing happen in shell or not.

Comment: Is format 1 in American (month-day-year) or in European (day-month-year) style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, using `awk`:

```
date='31-01-2014'
filetosearch=$(echo "$date" | awk -F- '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1}')
```

And, using `sed`:

```
filetosearch=$(echo "$date" | sed 's/\(..\)-\(..\)-\(....\)/\3-\2-\1/')
```

The above assumes that `date` is in the European (day-month-year) format.  If your date is in American format, then just a minor change is needed:

```
date='01-31-2014' 
filetosearch=$(echo "$date" | awk -F- '{print $3"-"$1"-"$2}')
```

And:

```
filetosearch=$(echo "$date" | sed 's/\(..\)-\(..\)-\(....\)/\3-\1-\2/')
```